# Get user's email address based on his userID .net identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity-2

I have the following function that re-generate a confirmation email (to complete registration) in case of an expired link.

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("ResendConfirmationEmail")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ResendConfirmationEmail(string userId = "")
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userId))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "User Id is required");
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        if (userId.GetHashCode() != null)
        {
            var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(userId);
            var callbackUrl = new Uri(Url.Link("ConfirmEmailRoute", new { userId, code = code }));
            string subject = "Please confirm your account";
            string body = "Please confirm your account by clicking this : <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>";
            SendEmail(?????, callbackUrl, subject, body);
        }
        return Ok();
    }
```

How can I get the email of the user from the `webUsers` table based on his `userid`?

Comment: `UserManager` has a method called `FindByIdAsync`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fetch user from database using UserManager's FindByIdAsync and then get the email

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userId); 
var email = user.Email;
```